# Splitting a string using streams and returning a string with the same order of words

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a string containing words separated by one or more blank characters (space, tab, etc.). I'm trying to write the most optimized procedure possible that outputs the string with the same words in the same order, but separated by only one space.

I'm trying this but I still have a problem:

```
public class Test {  
    public static void main(String args[]) {  
        String str = "word1, word2 word3@+word4?.word5.word6";  
        Stream<String> stream = Arrays.stream(input.split( "[, ?.@]+_" ));  
            .stream().collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
    }  
}
```

Comment: "but I still have a problem". So which one is it?

Comment: If you want computationally fast, and you know the separators are always just a single character as in your example, use a char array and manually replace

Comment: We can have one or more blank characters. Thanks for your comment Jems , I've edited my example.

Comment: What's the problem? Is it the stray `_`? I'm guessing `[, ?.@]+_` should be `[, ?.@_]+`.

Comment: Why use Stream for this? A simple `s = s.replaceAll("\\P{Alnum}+", " ").trim()` can do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split by one or more non-word characters `\W+` and collect using `Collectors.joining`

```java
String input = "word1, word2 word3@word4?word5.word6";  

String str = Arrays.stream(input.split( "\\W+" ))
                    .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
System.out.println(str);
```

Comment: Why not just `str = input.replaceAll("\\W+", " ")` and lose that Stream overhead?

Comment: This is possible too. As for "why Stream?" - should have asked myself this question before answering

Answer (score 1):

Is this your requirement?

```java
String s = "abc  a    b";
System.out.println(s.replaceAll("\\s+", " ")); // abc a b
```

Or if you need to remove any non-alpha numeric character as word boundary too and remove them, then please use this

```java
  String s = "abc  a+.?b    c";
  System.out.println(s.replaceAll("\\W+", " ").replaceAll("\\s+", " ")); // abc a b c
```

Thank you @ohn Kugelman for fixing

Answer (score 0):

In this case to get fast computation I think we can use `String.charAt(i)` method.
We have to use the `ASCII` values of each characters,

- Digits `0 to 9` has `ASCII` values of `48 to 57`
- Capital letters `A to Z` has `ASCII` values of `65 to 90`
- Small letters `a to z` has `ASCII` values of `97 to 122`
- `Space` or `" "` has `ASCII` value of `32`

Except this `ASCII` values we will eliminate all other `ASCII` values.

```
String str = "word1,     word2 word3@+word4?.word5.word6";  
String newStr = "";
boolean flag = false;
for(int i = 0 ; i < str.length(); i++){
    int charAsciiValue = (int)str.charAt(i);
    if((charAsciiValue >= 48 && charAsciiValue <= 57) || (charAsciiValue >= 65 && charAsciiValue <= 90) || charAsciiValue >= 97 && charAsciiValue <= 122){
        newStr += str.charAt(i);
        flag = true;
    }
    else if(charAsciiValue == 32 && flag){
        newStr += " ";
        flag = false;
    }else if(charAsciiValue != 32 && flag){
        newStr += " ";
        flag = false;
    }
}
System.out.println(newStr);
```

Output:

```
word1 word2 word3 word4 word5 word6
```